# What is the difference between selecting $3$ balls from $5$ balls and distributing $5$ balls into $3$ boxes?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the difference between the two cases?

1. selecting $3$ balls from $5$ balls
2. distributing $5$ balls into $3$ boxes

Comment: Please check that I did not change the meaning of the second case when I edited your question.

Comment: There seems to be more ways to distribute 5 balls into 3 boxes, since you have to account for the ways in which you can have 2 balls in each of 2 boxes, and also the ways to have 3 balls in one of the boxes. This is inherently different from choosing 3 balls out of 5 balls, where the 2 unchosen balls don’t affect the chosen combination. Does that make sense?

Comment: A crucial aspect of problem formulation is designating whether the balls (resp. the boxes) are *distinguishable* or *indistinguishable*.  For the former we often say the balls are colored differently or the boxes are labeled (e.g. numbered), so that outcomes depend on how individual balls or boxes are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second example, some balls must be in the same box, and there's the question of which ones, and whether they are three in on box and one in each of the other two, or three in one box and two in one of the other two, or two in each of two boxes and one in the third, and there may also be the question of which balls end up in which boxes. There are many more ways this could turn out than in the first question.

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways to distribute $5$ balls into $3$ boxes.

Even if the boxes are indistinguishable (and if they are distinguishable, there are even more ways yet), you could for example choose $3$ of the $5$ balls to put into one box (which equals the number of ways in which you can select $3$ out of $5$ balls), but after that you still have a choice whether you put the $2$ remaining balls into one of the other boxes, or to put $1$ ball into each of the remaining two boxes.

Of course, there are also ways to distribute $5$ balls into $3$ boxes where none of the boxes end up with exactly $3$ balls (e.g. one box ends up with all $5$ balls) and so there are even more choices yet.

Comment: While you have hit on the essential point, there are fewer ways to place the balls in indistinguishable boxes than distinguishable ones, so I do not understand your first parenthetical remark.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig By 'if they are' I meant they are distinguishable ... but yes, that was not at all clear, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

1. How many ways you can choose 3 balls from 5 balls =$\binom{5}{3}$
2. You can get different answer depending on the capacity of boxes.

   lets say if we can put any number of balls into boxes,
   we have the following cases 
   (5,0,0)(4,1,0)(3,2,0)(2,2,1)(3,1,1)
   which gives different answer depending on whether the boxes can be consider identical or different.